# Is it possible to forward an FTP request from a reverse proxy server?

Tags: iis, ftp, reverse-proxy

We have an ftp server no more accessible from the internet that we want to keep isolated, but still need to provide access to that ftp through a reverse proxy server with IIS.

Is there a way to define on IIS an *ftp site* that will just forward to the isolated ftp server?

Comment: The term *redirect* is used for cases where some proxy/server informs the client to look at another location and the client then does another request to the new location. Given that the FTP server is internal and not reachable directly by the client redirecting make no sense. The correct term for your question would be *forward*. I've fixed your question accordingly.

Comment: Reverse proxy (IIS ARR) only applies to HTTP. If you want to expose an internal FTP service to external users, you need firewall/gateway (ISA Server for instance) configuration. But Microsoft has retired its relevant product line and you need to buy third party products (or check what your firm already has with your network administrators).

Comment: Let me understand, can I configure a firewall/gateway system in the exposed server to forward requests to my internal ftp (and if so what do you recommend), or is this something that doesn't concern the exposed server?